X session is not starting with the network disabled
I have an Ubuntu 22.04.4 installation with a Xanmod 15 khz patched kernel and bash startup and a tty1 override for a custom script launch.
This script launches an X session with openbox plus a videogame frontend; when I finish this session it launches an XFCE4 desktop.
I have a wifi connection, and all was working well, but since any update, if I disable manually this connection the first X session do not launches, it shows this error:
vesa: Ignoring device with a bound kernel driver
(EE) Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found(EE)

... and some seconds after the system starts the XFCE4 session.
I have manually revised a lot of logs, and I don´t see what is causing this issue.
Can you help me? I could post here any needed log. Thank you in advice.  

It sounds like you are running your own modified kernel. This has then become a non Ubuntu question.

Thanks @David. Is Ubuntu an inmutable linux distro? It was working well with custom kernels. I have discovered that removing the conection parametres works, I don´t know what is making different when I uncheck the "network" or "wifi" options in Gnome wifi applet.
